# Nginx $ssl_client_raw_cert pem encoding

Tags: nginx, certificate, encoding

In nginx when using the `$ssl_client_raw_cert` to get the cert as a pem in the header; is it just the encoded cert or is it in the following format?

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----
>
> Encoded Cert
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE -----

the doc says

> returns the client certificate in the PEM format for an established SSL connection;

Comment: Based on a sample of one, the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----` marker is definitely present.

Comment: @RichardSmith you got it off the server? else if you have any link to the sample you saw much appreciate it.

Comment: I use client certificates on one of my servers, so I just had a look at that variable.